# SELECT with JOIN and condition and without JOIN in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have two tables:

`company`
id
name

`owner`
company_id
verified

There is no `owner` records, presented in DB without associated `company`.

But we have `company` records, presented in DB without `owner`.

How to select all companies with only verified owners and companies without owners with one query?

I've tried many queries and no one is working :(

For example, this query is not working:

```sql
select count(c.id) 
from company as c 
  left outer join owner o on c.id = o.company_id and o.verified is not null 
where not (c.id = o.company_id and o.verified is null);
```

### Sample schema

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ab366

```sql
create table company (
  id int unique,
  name varchar(255)
);

create table owner (
  first_name varchar(255),
  company_id int unique references company(id) on update cascade on delete set null,
  verified boolean
);

insert into company values (1, 'company1');
insert into company values (2, 'company2');
insert into company values (3, 'company3');

insert into owner values ('owner1', 1, true);
insert into owner values ('owner2', 2, false);
```

I need to select `company1` and `company3`.

Comment: share two tables sample data and expected output

Comment: Created SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ab366

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would actually use a left join from the `company` table to the `owner` table here:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN owner o
    ON c.id = o.company_id
WHERE
    o.company_id IS NULL OR    -- companies without owners
    o.verified IS NOT NULL;    -- companies with verified owners
```

Comment: You changed the `verified` column to boolean.  Use `o.verified = 1` to check for true in this case.

Comment: You only need `where coalesce(o.verified, true)` then the check for `o.company_id` is not needed http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ab366/9

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, exactly, it was a reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select c.*
from companies c
where not exists (select 1
                  from owners o
                  where o.company_id = c.id and
                        not o.verified
                 );
```

The primary reason for this is that a `left join` version can return duplicates if there are multiple verified owners.

A secondary reason is that this more closely captures the logic that you are describing . . . you want companies that have no unverified owners.